# Saving images from remote servers in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

I need to save the images from remote site. My host doesn't allow file_get_contents, so I am trying with curl. I am getting corrput images with the code. please help!

```
   $destination = realpath("../../app/webroot/img/uploads") . "/" . $facebook_id . "." . "gif";

    // Delete previous pic
    if (file_exists($destination)) {
        unlink($destination);
    }

    // Save new pic
    $remoteUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $facebook_id . "/picture";

    $ch = curl_init($remoteUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $fp = fopen($destination, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: have you looked at this corrupt data? is it a partial image? 0-length file? did you check if `$rawdata` is actualy a boolean false to signify curl failed somehow?

Comment: Having never worked with facebook, is it possible they are blocking you out some how?

Comment: @MarcB $rawdata is empty

Comment: then try `if ($rawdata === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }` and see what curl's complaining about. empty is visually indistinguishable from false. you should ALWAYS test return values from functions that deal with remote resources. your code could be perfectly fine, but if the remote resource is having trouble and your code doesn't handle that, you end up in situations like this.

Comment: @MarcB Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:10:6f01:face:b00c:0:8:

Comment: That's strange. Your code works for me. Seems more like a networking issue. does the URL `https://graph.facebook.com/someidhere/picture` work in your browser?

Comment: @MatthijsvandenBos url works fine on browser

Comment: Check extension of image to be scraped you have hard-coded extension to .gif

Answer (score 1):

`$fp = fopen($destination, 'wb');`

instead, to open them as binary files! :)

Comment: tried with wb, when i open image it show `image cannot be opened it contains errors`

Comment: set CURLOPT_READFUNCTION or CURLOPT_WRITEDATA maybe?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your server is resolving graph.facebook.com to an IPv6 address which isn't connecting for some reason.  If you're on php5.3+ you can try forcing curl to use IPv4:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);`

Comment: +1 was thinking of that as well, based on the error posted by the OP